# Are there anyways to work around errors given by ndefinedBehaviorSanitizer

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I have the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/lockfree/queue.hpp>

#define _ThreadPoolLength_  100

class thread_pool {
public:
    thread_pool() : q(_ThreadPoolLength_) {}

private:
    mutable boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void(int id)> *> q;
};

class Worker
{
    thread_pool workerPool;
};

Worker* worker;

int main() {
    worker = new Worker();
    delete worker;
    return 0;
}
```

If compile it with `clang++ -fsanitize=address,undefined code.cpp`, then during running it will produce something like:

> constructor call on misaligned address 0x6060000025a0 for type 'boost::lockfree::queue *>::node', which requires 64 byte alignment
>   0x6060000025a0: note: pointer points here
>
> 01 00 00 3c  40 25 00 00 60 60 be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be be be be be  be be be be
>                ^

```
#0 0x519fc5 in boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::node* boost::lockfree::detail::freelist_stack<boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::node, std::allocator<boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::node> >::construct<true, false, boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::node*>(boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::node* const&) 
#1 0x517e77 in boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::initialize() 
#2 0x51743c in boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void (int)>*>::queue(unsigned long) 
#3 0x51713f in thread_pool::thread_pool() 
#4 0x517048 in Worker::Worker() 
#5 0x516ed9 in main 
#6 0x7f6c3cb6bb96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
#7 0x41a5f9 in _start
```

> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior ...

I suspect the errors were caused by `boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void(int id)> *>`, but why? Are there any ways to work around it?

```
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
```

Finally, I replaced the use of `boost::lockfree::queue<std::function<void(int id)> *>` with a similar class by referring to [a blog post](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/).

Comment: Why there is no `delete`? If I add it, no leak is reported. As for misalignment, there are some reported issues such as [this](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/issues/11) and [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/11968) and [this](https://github.com/boostorg/lockfree/issues/52).

Comment: Sorry, I was stupid. I tried to strip down a large project and missed the delete operation. Now I have added delete, but the problem with UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer still reminds. I will update the question now.

Comment: @DanielLangr I see, thanks. it is a bug from Boost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're leaking `worker` because you used `new` to construct it and never use `delete` to destruct it. The other ASan messages are there because as part of constructing `worker`, its member queue is also constructed.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I tried to make the sampling code as small as possible to reproduce the problem from a larger project. Now I added back delete, but UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer still remains.

Comment: Alright, then yeah this is a Boost problem. This may be something that can be [suppressed](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#issue-suppression).

Comment: Putting __attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined"))) in front of thread_pool's constructor or even the main function doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Since it's somebody else's file, maybe try the `.supp` suppression file